# Deriving commutation relations $[X_i,P_j]=i \hbar \delta_{ij}\mathbf{I}$ for position with translation generator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

I am trying to show that for translations in 3D, the commutation relation between a component of position $\mathbf{X}$ and a component of the translation generator $\mathbf{P}$ is given by

$$[X_i,P_j]=i \hbar \delta_{ij}\mathbf{I}$$

where $\mathbf I$ is the identity operator.

According to my lecturer, this can be derived by expanding the translation operator for an infinitesimal translation $\delta \mathbf{a}$ as

$$U(\delta \mathbf{a})=\mathbf{I}-i \delta \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{P}/\hbar$$ to first order, then writing $$U^\dagger \mathbf{X} U=\mathbf{X}+\delta \mathbf{a}$$ and equating coefficients of $\delta \mathbf{a}$ to obtain
$$\frac{i}{\hbar}[\delta \mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{P},\mathbf{X}]=\delta \mathbf{a}. \hspace{1cm}(*)$$
My lecturer then claims that since this result above is true for arbitrary 3D infinitesimal translations $\delta \mathbf a$, it must also be true for the Cartesian components of the translation generator and hence it follows that

$$[X_i,P_j]=i \hbar \delta_{ij}\mathbf{I}.$$

I’m not sure how this follows from $(*)$, however. How are you meant to go from the dot product of operators to considering the Cartesian components themselves? It would be helpful if someone could spell this out more directly.

Comment: since $\delta\mathbf{a}$ is arbitrary you can also choose $\delta\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{e}_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin with the general relation
$$\frac{i}{\hbar}[\delta\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{P},\mathbf{X}]=\delta\mathbf{a}. \tag{*}$$

Since this is valid for every $\delta\mathbf{a}$
you can choose the special case $\delta\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{e}_j$
(the unit vector in $x_j$ direction).

$$\frac{i}{\hbar}[\mathbf{e}_j\cdot\mathbf{P},\mathbf{X}]=\mathbf{e}_j$$

$$\frac{i}{\hbar}[P_j,\mathbf{X}]=\mathbf{e}_j$$
Then scalar-multiply this equation with the unit vector $\mathbf{e}_i$.
You get
$$\frac{i}{\hbar}[P_j,\mathbf{X}]\cdot\mathbf{e}_i=\mathbf{e}_j\cdot\mathbf{e}_i$$
$$\frac{i}{\hbar}[P_j,\mathbf{X}\cdot\mathbf{e}_i]=\mathbf{e}_j\cdot\mathbf{e}_i$$

$$\frac{i}{\hbar}[P_j,X_i]=\delta_{ij}$$